# Dynamically allocating a float matrix?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there any way how to `malloc()` a 2D matrix in C? I have successfully tried `malloc()`ing a 1D field, but in matrix I am getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> float *mat2d = malloc( rows * cols * sizeof( float
>   ));

to access a value from the matrix use this adressing scheme:

> float val = mat2d[ x + y * cols ];

Comment: Thanks, I am assuming, that x and y are coordinates and cols referrs to columns.

Comment: @Hmyzak You're welcome. Yes my intention was to indicate that x,y are coordinates in this 2d matrix.

Answer (score 1):

If the size of the array isn't known at compile time you have to use a loop to allocate memory for each row.

Here's some sample code I found:

```
double** allocate2D(int nrows, int ncols) {
  int i;
  double **dat2;
  /*  allocate array of pointers  */
  dat2 = malloc( nrows*sizeof(double*));

  if(dat2==NULL) {
    printf("\nError allocating memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  /*  allocate each row  */
  for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    dat2[i] = malloc( ncols*sizeof(double));
  }
  if(dat2[i-1]==NULL) {
    printf("\nError allocating memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return dat2;
}
```

From [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/134284-initializing-2d-array-dynamically-allocated.html)

Be sure to change the data type from double to whatever you need.